# Constraint on curvature of polynomial approximation for camera calibration

Tags: polynomials, approximation

OpenCv uses the following polynomial for estimating lens distortion. More information can be found [here](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/calib3d/doc/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html).

$\frac{1+k_1r^2+k_2r^4+k_3r^6}{1+k_4r^2+k_5r^4+k_6r^6}$

There is a lot more to the calculation than just that but I think for the question that is all that is needed. When OpenCv is calculating the approximation it uses a bundle adjustment which I believe to be the Levenberg/Marquardt. OpenCv in general does well with regular lens, but fisheye lens seems to be problematic. The main issue is coverage of the calibration points. If you do not fully cover the image with calibration points the LM adjustment will (as expected) produce a rather nice estimation for the area covered by the calibration points but get rather radical in areas where no points are.

So onto my question, is there a mathematical way to provide an error/constraint into the Hessian matrix that would take the curvature of the approximation into account as so to penalize radical approximations?

Comment: I don't believe you have sufficiently narrowed the problem to one that can be treated mathematically.  The general idea is sensible:  you want to avoid oscillatory behaviour outside the "calibration" area.  But it's unclear whether you expect to be told that a feature of OpenCv exists to address this behaviour or what mathematical approaches *not implemented* by this software are known.

Comment: Looking for what mathematical approaches not implemented by this software are known. I would be more than happy to implement it in OpenCv, I understand the equations and code dealing with the calibration I just don't have a strong enough math background on how to setup (or even if it is possible) to constrain it in this manner.